# Is AWS(S3, EC2) a good backend fit for an appcelerator mobile app?

Tags: database, amazon-s3, appcelerator

I am looking to supplement a website i am building using web2py with a mobile app. Titanium seems good to work with and was wondering if i should just use AWS for my backend on both my website and mobile app. I am also interested in an answer if i was just developing the mobile app only not a website as well.

Kind Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created a simple API to access data from an app I developed with Titanium. It is hosted on EC2 and I have been very happy with the performance so far.